# parse_ini_file() keep outputing an error when i use it

Tags: php, config, ini

Okay for some reason i was using `parse_ini_file()` and i keep getting an error message, it says

> Warning: syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE in app/config.ini on line 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

My config.ini contains

```
[meta]
keywords=%nodata%
description=%nodata%
author=Nicholas English
email=nenglish443@gmail.com
robots=all
dnsprefetch=off
cachecontrol=no-cache
fragment=!
```

My index.php contains

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file("app/config.ini", true);
$meta = $config['meta'];
?>
```

I have search on google and no luck and i have tried doing it my self but it still wont work.

Any help would be amazing, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an empty line at the end of the file?

Comment: empty line or not it still shows that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INI_SCANNER_RAW` option:

```
$config = parse_ini_file("app/config.ini", true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

In default mode (`INI_SCANNER_NORMAL`) PHP prohibits exclamation mark in unquoted value:

> If a value in the ini file contains any non-alphanumeric characters it needs to be enclosed in double-quotes (").

So whether use the raw scanner, or quote the values with non-alphanumeric values, e.g.:

```
fragment="!"
```